# What event is late enough to not impact PageSpeed?

Tags: javascript, performance, dom-events, user-experience

(Note, this isn't about making a random tool giving me a better number; I'm diagnosing a landing page that is having terrible performance, and based on the web vitals assessment, real users are taking nearly 10 seconds to get to interactive!)

I don't think I'm using very much JavaScript, but apparently what I am using is quite slow (Google Tag Manager and Stripe each add between 500-700 ms!!).

I've managed to get https://pagespeed.web.dev/ into the upper 80s / lower 90s for mobile, but I've done so by delaying all JavaScript. Now I only load 1 script, and that script loads the other scripts after either 5000ms or first user interaction (I check for `mouseover`, `keydown`, `touchmove`, or `touchstart`).

So far so good. However, there are some scripts I'd like to load earlier (really, as soon as possible). I've tried

`window.onload = loadEarlyScripts();`

`document.body.addEventListener('load', loadEarlyScripts);`

and

```
document.body.addEventListener('readystatechange', () => {
  if ( document.readystate === 'complete' ) loadEarlyScripts;
});
```

But all of those drop my PageSpeed performance from 85-95 to ~ 45. So, the user-interaction events are good enough, but none of these are. What's the earliest event I can target that will make PageSpeed happy?

Comment: Are you sure the PageSpeed score is related just to WHEN the scripts are loaded? Maybe for example those scripts load huge images. Maybe those scripts are huge themselves. Maybe those scripts do repaints. Check the analysis of PageSpeed, it usually shorts suggestions by most impact.

Comment: The two in question are each about 50:50 load time and script execution time (350-500ms of each, for each script). If I delay them until 5s or user interaction, then the page is already fully loaded, so they don't impact the user's speed perception. I thought "window.onload" was "fully" loaded, but apparently not — if I load and execute them then, they still are impacting the pagespeed score (and presumably user experience).

Comment: (and they are, in fact, why PageSpeed is suggesting is the largest problem) ... if they're done at onload or earlier, but they don't show in the report if they're delayed.